# Pummeling Strike + Additional Effects

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Does a weapon effect such as Holy apply once to a character who is using a pummeling strike? Or does it apply to each consecutive hit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean [Pummeling Style](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/pummeling-style-combat-style), then yes, additional points and/or dice of damage would apply to every virtual "hit" - with the obvious limitation that it can only be used with unarmed strikes, so you'd need to be getting that Holy via an Amulet of Mighty Fists or the like. And if the entire pummel confirms as a critical, additional dice of damage don't get doubled, as usual.

Comment: Ok, so it is as written, you deal the normal amount of damage, normal being the entire and not just the base unarmed damage. Thank you